# What configuration is blocking local ssh connections to my server?

Tags: networking, ssh, debian, firewall, ufw

So I recently bought a Raspberry Pi to work on a small passion project with the RetroPie Debian-based image.
I am now at the stage where I want to completely shield the server only allowing specific connections to it. For my use case, they are as follows:

- Only allow inbound ssh connections from the same network the server is on
- Allow only outbound connections to specific IPs

To achieve this I have resorted to two different approaches: install and configure `ufw` for inbound/outbound connections and `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` for additional safety.

Here's my current setup:

```
hosts.allow

sshd: LOCAL
sshd: 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 # allow ssh from local network IPs only
sendmsg: 8.8.8.8 # allow ping google DNS to validate internet connectivity


hosts.deny

sshd: ALL


ufw:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24             # from local

XX.XX.XXX.XXX 443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to specific IP
XX.XX.XXX.XXX 443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to specific IP
XX.XX.XXX.XXX 443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to specific IP
140.82.121.4 443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to github
46.235.231.151 80/tcp      ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to raspberry registry
93.93.128.193 80/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to raspberry registry
XX.XX.XXX.XXX 443/tcp        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # to specific IP
```

What is currently happening is that whenever the server is rebooted, I am unable to connect via ssh from my machine (on the same network as Raspberry PI) which currently has an IP of `192.168.1.65` and, even though it may be dynamic, never leaves the specific range of IPs on `hosts.allow`.

Whenever I restart the server I need to manually use a keyboard connect to the Pi to `sudo systemctl stop ufw` in order for ssh connections to be available, but **why** if I have set an inbound rule on `ufw` to allow tcp connections on port 22 from the local IP range? Am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"install and configure ufw for inbound/outbound connections and hosts.allow and hosts.deny for additional safety."* IMHO combining those two will only increase confusion and increase the odds for operator error. TCP wrappers as a security mechanism is nowadays more a relic than added security. But opinions differ

Comment: Guess I can stick only to `ufw` then, but nevertheless it seems that the issue isn't with the `hosts.allow` or `hosts.deny` files which still begs the question as to why is `ufw` not allowing the inbound connection

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to why this solved the issue, but it seems to be working fine now after I disabled `PasswordAuthentication no` and `PermitEmptyPasswords no`, therefore defaulting ssh to force key authentication.

No changes were done to `hosts.*` files posted originally.

Also ran `sudo systemctl restart sshd` and `sudo systemctl restart ufw` to refresh any changes. Rebooted the system and I can now login using the generated private/public key pair.